Keras product regression model
I try to Use a simple keras model to predict product sales, It perform normal when i use keras.datasets.boston_housing.
the code:
all_datas = all_datas.dropna() 
all_datas = all_datas.drop_duplicates()
all_datas = all_datas[(all_datas != 0).all(axis=1)]

X = all_datas.iloc[:, :-1].values  
y = all_datas.iloc[:, -1].values  

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=HeNormal()))  
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))               
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))            
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f'Test Loss: {loss}')
predicted_sales = model.predict(X_test)
print(f'Predicted Sales: {predicted_sales}')

I use my data ，It has 4 characteristic values， some data like thie:
Ranking, price, rating, shipping cost, sales volume
5,15.2,4.4,4.32,83910
6,11.5,4.5,6.83,49744
6,21.48,4.6,7.65,80483
8,18.97,4.6,6.83,84835
9,19.78,4.6,6.83,95493
......
660091,18,5,4.32,15
660098,21.99,4.4,4.84,12
660129,70.5,4.5,3.86,45

And the result is(Predicted Sales always 1)：
Train: accuracy: 0.0225 - loss: 93.2195 
Test Loss: [92.95513916015625, 0.024801211431622505]
Predicted Sales: [[1.][1.][1.]...]

I tried adding initial weights, modifying the number of network nodes, layers, and loss function, but the loss became huge and I didn't gain much.
Based on boston_housing, it works, so I was wondering if there might be a problem with the data, but I'm still in the beginner's stage and don't know how to distinguish data anomalies.
Can someone give me some advice？

Hi, I have reviewed your code and suggest using a sigmoid activation function
in the final layer instead of softmax.Try increasing the model complexity by
adding more neurons, and use techniques like dropout and batch normalization.
Finally, perform hyperparameter tuning using Keras Tuner to optimize the
model. These changes will enhance the model performance
